# C++ Loop Algorithm Logic Issue

Tags: c++, algorithm, loops, vector, logic

```
int k = 0;

for (int a = 0; a < Ticket.size(); a++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 6; ++j)
        {
            if (Ticket[a][i] == lotteryRandomNumbers[j])
            {
                k++;
            }
        }
    }
}

std::cout << "You matched: " << k << " number(s)" << std::endl;
```

Ticket is a Vector containing multiple Vectors of size 6.
lotteryRandomNumbers is an array containing 6 values

At the moment this loop checks all the values in all the vectors and checks to see what matches with the array. So if in all the vectors together 8 numbers match, it outputs 8 matches.

What I want it to do is output how many matches there are in each individual vector, for example in vector 1, there is 1 match, in vector 2 there are no matches, in vector 3 there are 2 matches etc.

The number of vectors can change and is unknown to the programmer

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a place to ask for homework, think and find a way to do it yourself

Comment: its not homework, its part of a much bigger assignment, and I'm stuck on this particular part, I'm not necessarily after the answer, just something to push me in the right direction

Comment: Hint: you can create new vector with size `Ticket.size()`, initialize its values with `0`, then use `vectors_matches[ current_vector_id ]++;` before/after `k++;`. Then use this new vector for whatever you need.

Comment: @luxsypher this isn't a bad question, he's asking for help. That's what StackOverflow is for?

Comment: shift the output into the most outer loop and reset k afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It gets as simple as adding a variable in the outer loop and count how many matches we get per vector and then print it out at the end:

```
int k = 0;

for (int a = 0; a < Ticket.size(); a++) 
{
    int count_vec = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 6; ++j)
        {
            if (Ticket[a][i] == lotteryRandomNumbers[j])
            {
                count_vec++;
                k++;
            }
        }
    }
    std::cout   << "In vector " << a 
                << " there are " << count_vec 
                << " matches" << std::endl;
}

std::cout   << "You matched: " << k 
            << " number(s)" << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can declare a vector of matches.

```
vector< int > matches( Ticket.size(), 0 );

for (int a = 0; a < Ticket.size(); a++)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < Ticket[a].size(); ++i)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < 6; ++j)
    {
      if (Ticket[a][i] == lotteryRandomNumbers[j])
      {
        matches[a]++;
      }
    }
  }
}

for ( int i = 0; i < matches.size(); i++ )
  cout << matches[i] << " ";
```

Comment: You can even remove the `count` variable and use `++matches[ a ];` instead, as `matches`' values are zero-initialized. That's exactly what I suggested in my comment, +1.